# Android Alarm manager not firing when device is in sleep mode

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a reminder app for tablets.
My problem is that if the tablet is in sleep mode the alarm isn't getting called.
i tried a lot off project on github none of them wase working when my tablet wase in sleep mode.

My code is the following:

The code to set the alarm:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RingAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent("kidsplaylist.info.waketest.MyWakefulReceiver");

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);


        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

The code of the receiver:

```
public class MyWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakeLocker.acquire(context);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while the service is
    // launching. This is the Intent to deliver to the service.
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
    startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

The code for the service that is supposed to ring the alarm:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    // Do the work that requires your app to keep the CPU running.
    String song = Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI.toString();

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(song));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    MyWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Can anyone with experience in such thick advice me how to fix it

Thank's a lot

Avi

P.B: When the device is connected to the charger or when the screen is on it works OK
The problem is when the device screen is off.

Comment: have you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

Note that on Android 6.0+, Doze mode and app standby will affect `AlarmManager` events.

Beyond that, using an `IntentService` to directly play media will not work well. Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, the `IntentService` is destroyed, and your process will typically be terminated shortly thereafter.

I strongly recommend that you raise a `Notification` that uses this media as a ringtone. That would eliminate the need for the service entirely (you could raise the `Notification` in `onReceive()`, since that should be fairly quick to execute). It gives the user more control over whether the music plays (via `Notification` controls on Android 5.0+), and it gives the user a straightforward way to shut it up (swipe away the `Notification`).

If you insist upon playing the media yourself, you will need to use a regular `Service` and manage your own `WakeLock`, so that you can keep all that outstanding while the media is playing. Use an `OnCompletionListener` to `stopSelf()` the service and `release()` the `WakeLock` when the media is done.

Comment: The problem is that the AlarmManager does not execute so i dont get the chance to deal with them Wakelock